# Stopping .toml files from corrupting at power outage (python)

Tags: python, toml

I have a little python Programm that gets data from a website and safes it into a toml file. *Using toml so I can easily access the String.*
One time I when I was running the script power went off and when I turned my computer back on the file was full of `nullnullnullnull`

I want to find a way to stop this from happening.
I thought about using a temporary file that gets renamed but I don't know if it would work well with toml. I also thought about using a database but I only worked with Sql in HTML/php.
So if you have any ideas let me know.

UPDATE:
i tried using the atomicwrites pyhon library (look at nrdxp's answer) and it worked perfectly.

Instead of using:
`f = open("file", "w")`
im using `with atomic_write("file", overwrite=True)as f:`  and it works as i wanted it to. I tested it with ending the programm with the Task manager and pulling the Plug of my test computer.
The Result: no errors.

Comment: Are we talking about the literal four letters "null" or the byte 0 at the end of your file? If it's the former, then there's definitely something funky about the way you're writing it. Even if it's the latter, the OS should be taking care of committing writes, so what OS are you running all this on? Do you have a minimal example of the code that does this?

Comment: The entire file is replaced with "null" im running it on windows 10. Writing: f = open("file.toml") f.write("text", "w") f.close()

Comment: Keep a number of backups of the files if power outages happen often. Or buy backup power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to make updating the toml file an [atomic operation](https://wiki.osdev.org/Atomic_operation). A simple way to do this (at least on *nix systems) is to write to a temporary file and then rename the file once all the writes have completed.

If you need a more cross platform approach, there is also the [atomicwrites](https://github.com/untitaker/python-atomicwrites) python library.

Comment: Sounds interesting will try it out later 